# OneupUploaderBundle(blueimp) - save file

Tags: php, symfony

I have problem with configure blueimp. When I send file (click: start upload) in jsconsole is:

> POST XXXapp_dev.php/_uploader/gallery/upload 500 (Internal Server
>   Error)

I used:
[Simple example of the entity file to be uploaded with OneupUploaderBundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26341843/simple-example-of-the-entity-file-to-be-uploaded-with-oneupuploaderbundle)
https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupUploaderBundle/issues/51#issuecomment-24878715

My file:
services.yml:

```
Cms.upload_listener:
    class: Cms\AdminBundle\EventListener\UploadListener
    arguments: [@doctrine]
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: oneup_uploader.post_upload, method: onUpload }
```

config.yml:

```
oneup_uploader:
    mappings:
        gallery:
            frontend: blueimp
            storage:
                service:              ~
                type:                 filesystem
                filesystem:           ~
                directory:            web/uploads/gallery
                stream_wrapper:       ~
                sync_buffer_size:     100K
```

routing.yml

```
oneup_uploader:
    resource: .
    type: uploader
```

~Entity/File.php

```
/* ... */
    /**
     * @ORM\Entity
     * @ORM\Table(name="file")
     */
    class file {
        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         */
        protected $id;

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="string")
         */
        protected $filename;
    }
```

~/EventListner/UploadListner.php

```
class UploadListener
{
    protected $manager;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $manager)
    {
        $this->manager = $manager;
    }

    public function onUpload(PostPersistEvent $event)
    {
        $file = $event->getFile();

        $object = new file();
        $object->setFilename($file->getPathName());

        $this->manager->persist($object);
        $this->manager->flush();
    }
}
```

debug route:

> _uploader_upload_gallery       POST     ANY    ANY 
>   /_uploader/gallery/upload

Directory /web/uploads/gallery is on the server.

What am I trying to achieve? I need upload files to server and add record to db.

I think that config is incorrect, but where?

**Edit 1:** 
Maybe help

> INFO - An exception was thrown while getting the uncalled listeners
>   (Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Cms\AdminBundle\EventListener\UploadListener::__construct() must be an
>   instance of Cms\AdminBundle\EventListener\EntityManager, instance of
>   Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry given, called in
>   /home/cms/public_html/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on
>   line 455 and defined)  Context:
>   {"exception":"Object(Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException)"}
>
> CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception
>   Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\Exception\FileException: "Unable
>   to create the "/uploads/gallery" directory" at
>   /home/cms/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/File.php
>   line 134  Context:
>   {"exception":"Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\Exception\FileException)"}

I created uploads/gallery! chmod 777. I don't understand.

**Edit 2:**

```
Cms.upload_listener:
    class: Cms\AdminBundle\EventListener\UploadListener
    arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: oneup_uploader.post_upload, method: onUpload }
```

and:

```
directory:            ./uploads/gallery
```

Now created, uploaded file in "uploads/gallery/..."
But...

> CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception
>   Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException: "Catchable
>   Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Cms\AdminBundle\EventListener\UploadListener::onUpload() must be an
>   instance of Oneup\UploaderBundle\Event\PostPersistEvent, instance of
>   Oneup\UploaderBundle\Event\PostUploadEvent given" at
>   /home/cms/public_html/src/Cms/AdminBundle/EventListener/UploadListener.php
>   line 17  Context:
>   {"exception":"Object(Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException)"}

Returns blueimp "Internal Server Error ..." and doesn't add records in the Entity.

Comment: The 500 error would be generating an error in the log (via the log file or profiler). If you paste it that may help someone answer your question.

Comment: Yes the error would help you and us to know where it fails, also if you can xdebug it to see which line fails.

Comment: Update first post. xdebug?

Comment: You have wrong event, should be `event: oneup_uploader.post_persist`